# Same Table name and Column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

Customer is a table and "Customer" is one of the column in that table, When I create EDMX out of this table, "Customer" field suffixed with 1 (Customer1).

1. any specific reason?
2. can we rename column name as "Customer" instead.

Comment: Better to rename the column/table in the DB and refresh the EDMX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a limitation of the language, no, you can't rename it Customer. A class cannot contain a property or field with the same name of its containing type. So the EDMX designer adds the 1 at the end.

Why is this? Think about constructors and finalizers, they are special methods that have the same name as the containing type. If you have a property with the same name, the compiler will not be able to resolve the constructor because you can't overload a property with a method.

Either pick a better name for the table (Customer**s**) or the field.

Comment: +1 for the advice to pick a better name. A column named `Customer` on a table named `Customer` is pretty ridiculous.